# Selenium can't click button

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I click button "View profile" on this page.

**Problem:** when I want to copy XPath of "View profile" button, the button disappeares.

https://www.linkedin.com/sales/search/people?savedSearchId=515913166

[[image]]

**Another image**
[image]

This is my code. Reads email and password from config.txt file.
Goes to linkedin site, then goes to Sales Navigator
**My code**

```
import os, random, sys, time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Chrome('driver/chromedriver')

browser.get('https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login')

file = open('config.txt')
lines = file.readlines()
username = lines[0]
password = lines[1]

elementID = browser.find_element_by_id('username')
elementID.send_keys(username)

elementID = browser.find_element_by_id('password')
elementID.send_keys(password)

visitingSalesNavID = '/sales/homepage/'
fullLink = 'https://www.linkedin.com' + visitingSalesNavID
browser.get(fullLink)

time.sleep(4)

SavedSearchesID = '/sales/search/saved-searches/people'
fullLink = 'https://www.linkedin.com' + SavedSearchesID
browser.get(fullLink)

time.sleep(4)

SavedSearchID = '/sales/search/people?savedSearchId=515913166'
fullLink = 'https://www.linkedin.com' + SavedSearchID
browser.get(fullLink)

time.sleep(4)

browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html[1]/body[1]/div[5]/main[1]/div[1]/div[1]/section[1]/div[1]/ol[1]/li[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/article[1]/section[1]/div[2]/ul[1]/li[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/button[1]/li-icon[1]/*').click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to freeze the DOM:

1) Open the dev console (`F12` key)

2) Select `sources` tab

3) click `F8` to freeze the DOM

Then do whatever you do with that

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to look element’s detail. You can click with the `text`. Try below code after open menu.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(., 'View profile')]")))
element.click()
```

Comment: What exception?